# Matlab GUI-storing data onto a new variable using pushbutton

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I'm a beginner in MATLAB and hope someone can help me with this problem.

The GUI I created produce 'G' corresponding to user's frequency and amplitude inputs. For ex. `freq=[2 3 7]; AMPL=[2 3 4]`, the G produced is

```
7.8214    5.0132    1.7297
6.8302    4.3406    1.4855
6.3412    4.0536    1.3403
```

As a second ex. if user inputs,freq=[2 3] and AMPL=[3 4]; the G produced is

```
[6.9020    4.3621;
6.2893    4.0276]
```

Thus G can be of any size depending on the no. of freq and AMPL input. Min. size of G is [1 1] ie a single number and max. size it can be of [6 6];
what I want to do is to intoduce a pushbutton(save_G) in my GUI,which will save the G generated in another variable(lets say G5). thus once a user input a specific freq and AMPL and generate G, that G should save on G5 once the user enter save_G pushbutton. and again if the user inputs other values for freq and AMPL and generated a new G,this new G should add on to the G5(if user presses the save_G5 button).How do I store the old G value and append the new G value to the G5 on hitting the pushbutton? thus I want my G5 should look like as follows for the above examples.

```
G5=
freq(1)=[2 3 7]; AMPL(1)=[2 3 4];
G(1)=
7.8214    5.0132    1.7297
6.8302    4.3406    1.4855
6.3412    4.0536    1.3403

freq(2)=[2 3] ;AMPL(2)=[3 4];
G(2)=
6.9020    4.3621
6.2893    4.0276
```

Thus G5 should keep on saving Gs and have to be sorted in the ascending order of the first element of frequencies.

How can I achieve this? Looking forward for someone's help. assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I undersand your point, I think you should use a cell.

At the beginning of the program you initialize `G5` to en empty cell:

```
G5={};
```

and each time the user press a button, you should append the new G to G5:

```
G5=[G5 G];
```

for more information about cells, if you are a beginner:

http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html#br04bw6-117

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have tried the same using cell arrays.But I couldn't append the new G when the user presses the button.It erases the old G and only new G was displayed.

Comment: you were correct. I have found out why it was not attached in my case. Since I initialized G5 under the pushbutton instead of opening function each time when I press the pushbutton value of G5 will become null and so previous value is lost. Thanks a lot for your help.